# Are All Dimensions Infinite and 'Closed'?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, topology, spacetime-dimensions

I have formed a thread about loosely how a  'fluid', geometrically flat, N-space, that is 'curved', in infinity'. With flows of fluid, 'space', that can facilitate known forces in that flat space. In a more appropriate forum.
Fluid N-space.
https://www.quora.com/q/rbdckesbcmnzchke  .}

[I presume all dimensions are infinite in length, and  'wrap', in infinity. Like the surface of a (n infinite) sphere.*
{except, perhaps the 'tiny curled' ones in string theory.}

I believe I have an intuitive understanding of some 'extra dimensions' other than x,y,z, space, and time.
But before I mention those, I should test this basic assumption, about dimension 'wrap', first.

That all dimensions are infinite in length, and curved, in that infinity, to 'wrap', so that the infinite extension in one direction 'wraps back', to come from the infinite extension in the opposite direction.

I understand that all dimensions can be defined by infinite straight lines. Right?
Any finite length, in any direction, can be extended.
I suppose, some may want to haggle about the tiny curled dimrnsions hypothesized by string theorists.
Later.

The curvature of the circumference of a circle of infinite radius is zero.
Wikipedia tells me, " the canonical example is that of a circle, which has a curvature equal to the reciprocal of its radius. "
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

So. The circumference of a circle of infinite radius, is an infinite straight line.
This suggests to me, that infinite straight lines, are the circumference of circles of infinite radius.
(many circles).

Since any dimension may be defined by an infinite straight line.
I conclude. That all dimensions are curved, 'wrap back' apon themselves, in infinity.
{Or at least the infinite ones.}

This is the concept embodied in the symbology of the 'Worm Oroboros' . The snake, eating its tail.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros
In particular, I think this sybolizes the infinite past, coming from, resulting from, the infinite future.
'Time, is one of those infinite curved dimensions'.

Am I right, that infinite straight lines can be thought of as the cicumference of circles of infinite radii?
And. that infinite dimensions at least, may be defined by infinite straight lines? And, 'Wrap'?

Comment: Physicists do not assume that infinite dimensions wrap. The usual assumption is the opposite.

Comment: This question is about the way geometry handles infinitiy and the implications of this for cosmology. That is very much on-topic. I do not think it should have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

Many geometrical objects degenerate into straight lines as they grow arbitrarily large. Some of these lines loop back on themselves as you describe, others do not. The lines of Euclidean and affine spaces do not; the lines of projective, elliptic and spherical spaces do. The lines of hyperbolic spaces can get complicated. Each such space has a characteristic global topology, as an n-dimensional manifold whose topology may be defined by things called Betti numbers and torsion coefficients. Unfortunately, four is about the hardest number of dimensions to study mathematically and spacetime has four dimensions (even if only three of them are spatial). We do not know the global topology of spacetime, so we cannot know whether its lines are loops or not. For all we know, it may even be that some are and some aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Euclidean geometry a straight line is infinite in extent and can be thought of (loosely) as the limiting case of a circle as its radius approaches infinity.

In standard Euclidean geometry straight lines do not "wrap" in any sense. But there are other geometries which add one or more points "at infinity" to the Euclidean plane, and in these geometries straight lines can be said to wrap around back onto themselves.

We do not know whether the spatial dimensions of the universe are finite or infinite - although we do know that they are certainly very large in human terms. We also know that the universe does *not* have an infinite past - the existence of the Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation tells us that.

Comment: If the Universe has expanded from a finite "big bang" at a finite rate for finite time, then it is not infinite.

Comment: @GuyInchbald How do you know that the Big Bang was finite in extent ? We can only observe a finite portion of the universe, but that is not a limit on the universe itself. However, if you really can prove that the universe is finite then a Nobel prize may await you.

Comment: @GuyInchbald I don’t know what a “finite Big Bang” is, but for a mainstream Big Bang that’s not true. Read about Friedmann universes with $k=0$ and $k=-1$.

Comment: I didn't say I did. I said "if". However almost all descriptions of the Big Bang by professional cosmologists describe it as starting out very small, often expressed in terms of the Planck length, so it is a common hypothesis. One may alternatively assert that *if* (N.B.) the Universe is infinite then it must have either been expanding for ever, have expanded at an infinite rate at some point, and/or been infinite in size to start with.

Comment: @Guy *"However almost all descriptions of the Big Bang by professional cosmologists describe it as starting out very small*". Do they? Perhaps they're talking about the currently-observable universe, which was certainly small near the start of the Big Bang, whether the whole universe is finite or infinite.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't; sometimes they note that this tiny thing has inflated so fast we can only see part of it. The point I make is also periodically made by others; most physicists treat most mathematical infinities as boundary conditions where the model breaks down, why should the size of the Universe be the first infinity to break the rule?  So let's stop imagining up spurious provenance issues and accept that the case for infinity is not proven.